# После сжатия диска, освободившаяся память залетела на раздел с Linux

Tags: linux, память, windows-10, dual-boot, partition

У меня дуалбут W10/Kde neon.
Я решил сжать через винду диск `С`, на котором стояла винда. Почему-то в управлении дисками раздел с линуксом был отмечен как не распределенная память, я не придал этому значения. Скрин после форматирования:

[image: Скрин после форматирования]

После сжатия, освободившаяся память залетела в этот нераспределенный раздел и линукс теперь не загружается. Как мне восстановить его? Может можно откатить это как нибудь или разделить память внутри раздела?

Answer (score 1):

`Windows` **НЕ** поддерживает файловые системы `linux` (`ext`, `xfs` и `gpt` с ними), **НО** `Linux` поддерживает файловые системы `windows` (`ntfs`, `hpfs`) при установке дополнительных пакетов с драйверами.

Установку `dual-boot` системы рекомендуется проводить так:

1. Размечаем жесткий диск самостоятельно (например с помощью `acronis disk director`). Создаем один загрузочный раздел `mbr` `primary` `ntfs` и устанавливаем туда `windows`:

   ```
   | windows c:                                        |
   |---------------------------------------------------|
   | ntfs                                              |
   ```
2. После установки `windows` опять самостоятельно сжимаем размер диска до 20 Gb (должно хватить) и передвигаем его на третий раздел, добавляем первый и второй (тоже `mbr` `primary`). Загрузочным делаем раздел `linux root`:

   ```
   | linux swap | linux root | windows c: | linux home |
   |------------|------------|------------|------------|
   | RAM x2     | 10 Gb      | 20 Gb      | any        |
   ```

   Четвертый раздел - файлы пользователя `linux home` или `windows d:` (тоже `mbr` `primary`). В последних версиях `linux` можно вместо раздела подкачки `swap` использовать файл в разделе `root` (в `windows` это файл `pagefile.sys` на диске `c:`). Для некоторых материнских плат требуется раздел `efi` (достаточно 100 Mb).
3. В файле [`c:\\boot.ini`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot.ini) указываем, что `windows` переехала на третий раздел:

   ```
   multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(3)\WINDOWS
   ```
4. Устанавливаем `linux`, не беспокоясь о том, что `windows` после этого перестанет работать. Дальнейшие операции с жестким диском (по необходимости) проводим либо из `linux`, либо с помощью внешнего `bootable` ПО.

---

Лучше, если первые 3 раздела будут на отдельных `ssd` дисках, а еще лучше - на съёмных, но тогда порядок загрузки нужно будет выставлять на материнской плате.

Comment: Windows обязан видеть Linux-разделы как хотя бы просто неизвестные разделы, но не как нераспределённую память

Comment: Windows обязан понимать и всякие gpt тоже

Comment: А это уже загадка века, что-то где-то у автора серьёзно сломалось

Comment: @andreymal устанавливаю уже десятый раз дуалбутом, поэтому с файловыми системами был аккуратен. Установил сначала винду со схемой раздела GPT и за ней линукс с такой же схемой. Сам удивился, когда увидел в винде "нераспределенная память"